# Example of a surjective transformation that maps to the complement of the span of a known set of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $H$ be the Hilbert space of square integrable complex functions and let $S \subseteq H$ be a finite set of linearly independent functions of $H$. Can someone provide me an example of a surjective linear transformation that maps every function of $H$ to a function of $(H - \text{span }S) \cup \{0\}$?

Comment: Perhaps you want the projection onto $\text{span}(S)^\perp$?

Comment: Not exactly. The ortogonal set of $span(S) $ is not the set I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $H-\operatorname{span} (S)$  is not a vector space, so it can't be the image of a linear transformation.

Comment: Presumably surjective here means surjective as a function $H \to H$...?

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you for your point.

Comment: $(H - \text{span }S) \cup \{0\}$ is not a vector space neither

Comment: Could you clarify why?

Comment: Take any non zero vector $x$ in $\text{span}(S)$, and any non zero vector $y$ in $H - \text{span}(S)$. You can show that $x-y\in{H - \text{span}(S)}$, you then have both $y$ and $x-y$ in ${H - \text{span}(S)}$, but $y+(x-y)=x$ is not in ${H - \text{span}(S)}$. Usually, when working with vector spaces, you don't do such operations as taking the complementary of a set, or the difference or two sets, because the sets you obtain are not vector spaces. You usually take the orthogonal of a set, or his complementary, etc. You then obtain vector spaces.

Comment: Ok, I will mark your answer. Actually, I don't really need a linear transformation. Any transformation would suffice.